# Uncaught Error: Class "book" not found in C:\wamp64\www\projectindex.php but IDE can define it

Tags: php, doctrine

PHP project, trying to connect to database and persist object. Object can't be seen by the compiler for some reason.

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$connectionParams = [
    'dbname' => 'db',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
];


$he = EntityManager::create($connectionParams, Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__ . '/Entity']));
/*
$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__));
$dotenv->load();*/

header("Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Acces-Control-Allow-Headers: *");


/** DB connection */

$book = (new book())
    ->set_name("test")
    ->set_price("3")
    ->set_sku("1");
$he->persist($book);
$he->flush();
```

The error Class "book" not found yet it is defined by id (showing details such as superclass)

Comment: I have been trying for 3 hours and nothing is fixing this issue.

Comment: Have you setup an `autoload` in your composer.json file and run `composer dumpautoload` yet?

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure? I think 'book' is a homemade class, it doesn't sound like something imported from composer